# What is the difference between referencing a HEREDOC and a File when using expect

Tags: bash, expect

I have a script that connects to servers via ssh using expect and issues some commands.

When I run the expect script as HEREDOC it quits with an eof by the spawned shell after entering the Password, on the other hand when I run exactly the same script as a file it gives me a shell,  how can this be?

I try to use this snippet:

```
expect -d /dev/stdin <<- END
sleep 10
set timeout 20
eval spawn "ssh user@example.org"

expect "user@example.org's password: " { send -- "Passw0rd\r" }

interact
END
```

But everytime I try to connect I get an 'received eof' and and expect exits, no shell.

```
expect: does "\ruser@example.org's password: " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "rmh@user@example.org's password: "? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "rmh@user@example.org's password: "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\rrmh@user@example.org's password: "
send: sending "Passw0rd\r" to { exp6 }
interact: received eof from spawn_id exp0
```

On the other hand when I open exactly the same script as a file I get connected.

```
cat <<- END > interact.expect
sleep 10
set timeout 20
eval spawn "ssh ssh user@example.org"

expect "user@example.org's password: " { send -- "Passw0rd\r" }

interact
END

expect -d interact.expect
```

I tried multiple times and double checked the scripts being identical.

Could someone explain how this could be?

Comment: Avoid using `expect` to automate `ssh`; use public-key authentication instead.

Comment: Okay, but is is it safe to allow sudo with NOPASSWD in this case then?

Comment: That's an entirely different question.

Comment: If you're using SSH with public key auth you don't need sudo at all: you can configure a SSH public key to only be able to run a specific command as a specific user; if ssh is directly connecting to that account, no sudo required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is what happens when you get to the `interact` statement. This tells `expect` to connect its stdin to the pty that's feeding to the current command.

When `expect` is reading from a file, its `stdin` is still connected to the terminal, so `interact` will allow you to interact with the command using the terminal.

But when you use the here-doc, `stdin` is connected to the here-doc, the terminal connection is lost to the `expect` process. So `expect` gets EOF because you've reached the end of the here-doc.

You would see the same thing if you used redirection to read from the file instead of using a filename argument:

```
expect -d /dev/stdin < interact.expect
```

Comment: Ah makes sense! Thank you so much for the clarification! Couldn't get my mind around it.